# Entity Framework code-first re-create foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I accidentally deleted several tables of my database and manage to recover some parts of it.

But it seems that my foreign keys were not created after adding a new migration and running update-database command.

Code for missing foreign key constraint that is missing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File.File>()
        .HasRequired(f => f.FileType)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<File.FileType>()
        .HasMany(a => a.ApplicationUsers)
        .WithMany(a => a.FileTypes);
```

Is there a way that I can re-create the keys using code-first?

PS: I tried to run 'update-database -force' but it didn't solve my problem.

PS2: It's my test database, if you were wondering, but I like to learn how to fix this anyway.

Comment: did you have any data in the database that you'd like to keep ?

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<File.File>()
        .HasRequired(f => f.FileType)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);  here withmany should have a entity  representing one to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Into one to many relationship You need to add:

```
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.Id_Representation_In_Foreign_Table)
```

Many to many relationship:

```
            .HasMany(i => i.ApplicationUsers)
            .WithMany(i => i.FileTypes)
            .Map(m => // use map if you're overwriting convention, otherwise sql will create name of the columns automatically
            {
                m.ToTable("FileTypesAndSmth");
                m.MapLeftKey("ApplicationUserId");
                m.MapRightKey("FileTypeId");
            });
```